# Drupal module for inline notifications (in style of Stackoverflow or Gmail)?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I am looking for a Drupal module that makes on-page notifications similar to those found on Stackoverflow (slide on from top) or Gmail (appears near top of page).
I've looked through the secondary modules associated with notifications and messaging projects, and haven't found this.
The module needs to be able to hook into other core modules in order to be triggered by events and send useful messages (i.e. i'm not looking for just the javascript to do a pop-up).
BTW this is for Drupal 6. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a module which exactly does what you describe, but you would get **very** far with one of the "growl" messaging modules mentioned in [this comparison chart](http://groups.drupal.org/node/51088).

For example the "rawr" module which I think could be easily modified to fit your needs. Some css and theming would be necessary probably.

They all only work with the default drupal messages (created with drupal_set_message). However, since this is the common way in drupal to display messages, other modules should work fine with it.